# How to pass valueOf method which has several overrides as parameter to method

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm interested to write a generic split method, that can be invokes like this:

```
List<String> names = splitField("John, Nate, Larry", String::valueOf);
List<Integer> ages = splitField("35, 23, 48", Integer::valueOf);
```

Here is my implementation:

```
private <T, R> List<R> splitField(String stringWithComma, Function<T, R> valueOf) {
    List<R> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    if (stringWithComma != null && !stringWithComma.isEmpty()) {
        elements = Arrays.stream(stringWithComma.split(","))
                .map(valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return elements;
  }
```

It doesn't build, What am I missing here?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

This implementation builds and works well went invoked with `String::valueOf`, but throws exception when invoked on `Integer::valueOf`

```
private <R> List<R> splitField(String elementsWithComma, Function<String, R> valueOf) {
    List<R> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    if (elementsWithComma != null && !elementsWithComma.isEmpty()) {
        elements = Arrays.stream(elementsWithComma.split(","))
                .map(valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return elements;
  }
```

Comment: *It doesn't build* ... but what does the error read? Tried debugging? For the Edit-1, did you `trim` the Strings?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace and error message, so this question is helpful to other users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring a type parameter `T` where you actually want `String`, as the function is supposed to process a value you know to be a `String` to `R`. Remove the type parameter `T` and change the function to `Function<String, R>`.

```
private <R> List<R> splitField(String stringWithComma, Function<String, R> valueOf) {
  List<R> elements = new ArrayList<>();
  if (stringWithComma != null && !stringWithComma.isEmpty()) {
      elements = Arrays.stream(stringWithComma.split(",\\s*"))
              .map(valueOf)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  return elements;
}
```

Note that I also change the split pattern to let it consume the space after commas, to avoid parse exceptions.

Following the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488) rule, you can relax the function signature, to support more use cases.

```java
private <R> List<R> splitField(
        String stringWithComma, Function<? super String, ? extends R> valueOf) {
  List<R> elements = new ArrayList<>();
  if (stringWithComma != null && !stringWithComma.isEmpty()) {
      elements = Arrays.stream(stringWithComma.split(",\\s*"))
              .map(valueOf)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  return elements;
}
```